# Calculus, volume between plane and paraboloid - check my answer

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Fairly simple question, we have the paraboloid $z=a(x^2+y^2)$ and the plane $z=h$. $a,h >0$

Find the volume of the region bounded by the plane and the paraboloid.

What I did:

It is clear to see $a(x^2+y^2) \leq z \leq h$ from the way the question is written.

The hard part which im not sure of is the limits of $x,y$.

$a(x^2+y^2) = ax^2+ay^2 \leq h$ implies: $- \sqrt{\frac{h-ax^2}{a}}\leq y \leq \sqrt{\frac{h-ax^2}{a}}$

the minimal value of $y^2$ is zero. and if that happens, then $ax^2 \leq h$, which implies $-\sqrt{\frac{h}{a}} \leq x \leq \sqrt{\frac{h}{a}}$

So the volume we are looking for is in my opinion:

$$\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{h}{a}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{h}{a}}} \int_{- \sqrt{\frac{h-ax^2}{a}}}^{ \sqrt{\frac{h-ax^2}{a}}} \int_{a(x^2+y^2)}^{h}dzdydx$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This looks correct.  You can also take advantage of the axial symmetry of the paraboloid by integrating over, say, only the first quadrant, and multiplying the volume result by 4.  Another approach would be to consider that the horizontal cross-sections of the paraboloid are all circles with radii dependent only on $ \ z \ $ ; you can then reduce the volume integral to one over a single variable.  (If you are _required_ to write a triple integral for the volume, you can use this second technique as a check...)  You might also consider a triple integral in _cylindrical_ coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Cylindrical coordinates. Starting: $ax^2 + ay^2 = h \to x^2 + y^2 = r_0^2$ with $r_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{h}{a}}$. So set $x = r\cos\theta$, and $y = r\sin\theta$, then we integrate:

$z: ar^2 \to h$

$r: 0 \to \sqrt{\dfrac{h}{a}}$

$\theta: 0 \to 2\pi$. Thus the set up is:

$V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{h}{a}}} \int_{ar^2}^h rdzdrd\theta$